# How to start MasterDetailPage below StatusBar?

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms, master-detail

How to i can start MasterDetailPage below Status Bar ?
Is it possible ?
How can i do it ?

I created a MastePage and add the icon in her and setting her in the MainPage:

```
this.Master = new MasterPage();
this.Detail = new NavigationPage(new DetailPage());
```

Answer (score 0):

Extend MainActivty from FormsApplicationActivity like

```
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsApplicationActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);

        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init (this, bundle);

        LoadApplication (new App ());
    }
}
```